# Can I check for modifications on a different path to the one that is checked out?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a project with a [`sourcecontrol`](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Subversion%20Source%20Control%20Block.html) block which has a trunk url value.

I also use [`intervalTrigger`](http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Interval%20Trigger.html) with modification exists property.

I'd like to only build if there are modifications in a sub path of the trunk url, anyone know how I might do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following post, I think it's related:
[how to customize buildCondition="IfModificationExists" on CruiseControlNet build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736756/how-to-customize-buildcondition-ifmodificationexists-on-cruisecontrolnet-build/15758319)

and there's the filtered source control block which should do what you need:
http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered